# How can i send a SMS via an API

Tags: monitoring, sms

How can i send an international SMS (or place a call) with a HTTPS request? 
What reliable service providers do you know / use? 
I want to use a SMS service instead of a hardware aproach.

Comment: You will need to tell us what country you are in, or which country you want to send most of your SMS's to

Comment: Romania, Europe - different service providers.

Comment: Try this guide with mySMS: https://serverfault.com/questions/1014322/send-and-receive-sms-with-mysms

Comment: Try mySMS:
Guide here -- https://serverfault.com/questions/1014322/send-and-receive-sms-with-mysms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've had good service from [Clickatell](http://www.clickatell.com), who are based in South Africa. They have APIs via several different methods including https and smtp.

Comment: i have signed up with them. but they don't seem to have activated my account... i wonder if they do world-wide or just... select-countries.  i'll contact support in 36h

Comment: too bad they do not have any trial perior. or free number of sms'es.

Answer (score 2):

I am in Australia and have used Clickatell before from a rails application via API as well as via smtp from nagios. No problems in the past 12 months.

Answer (score 1):

[MX Telecom](http://www.mxtelecom.com/tech/sms/http) provide a pretty good service in EMEA and NA using a simple HTTP[S] GET interface.

Usual features such as originator address, flash messages, multipart and delivery reports are included.

Answer (score 0):

There is another provider with an HTTPS API called TextMagic. They provide wrapper libraries for their HTTPS API in a number of languages.

(Full disclosure: I am the author of the Python wrapper library at [textmagic-sms-api-python](http://code.google.com/p/textmagic-sms-api-python/))

Answer (score 0):

The TextMagic API allow you to send sms messages to landline phones too?
If not, you can add this feature to the system. See text2land.com

Mike